# Probability of radioactive decay of a non-uniform system

Tags: probability-distributions

It is given that the probability that one among two radioactive atoms will decay in an interval $x,x+dx$ and another one will decay in a time interval $y+dy$ is given by the following expression:
$$Ne^{-y\alpha-x\beta-\gamma\sqrt{xy}}dydx$$ 
where $\alpha, \beta>0$, and $\gamma~\epsilon~R$.

How can I determine the expected value and standard deviation of decay time for both atoms in analytical form?
Also, how do I numerically calculate the approx. probability that one of them decays prior to the other?

Comment: This is just a joint distribution. What is the research interest?

Comment: I wanted to generalize this to a n-radioactive chain with decay happening at definite $\delta t$ intervals, but was stuck at the initial part of it.

Comment: well, you just integrate over $x$ to get the marginal distribution of $y$, and if you want to know the probability that $x$ decays before $y$ you integrate over over $x$ from $0$ to $y$ and then over $y$ from $0$ to $\infty$. (no closed form expression, this is an integral you'll need to evaluate numerically)